# Java: Dividing a single array by a object element value in to 2 arrays

Tags: java, arrays, element, divide

Edit. thank you.

I have an array of 'normal' vehicles and 'large' vehicles. I have an assignment requiring me to divide them up to contribute to a far larger app. 
One array for the large vehicles, one for the normal vehicles containing all the info for each element. ArrayLists are not permitted as my instructor is teaching us fundamentals.

Sample of the array

`27723  4/09/61     large   7337
28507   22-02-1983  large   7055
28558   1/05/70     normal  3518`

```
//On button press
//recieve single item from array from main and test it
//array in main will be looped for all elements. 
public String loadVehicle(Vehicle v) {
String res = Constants.OK;

boolean normBool = false;
boolean largeBool = false;

//if both arrays are full , stop the method call in the main form
if (normBool && largeBool){return Constants.ERROR;}

//if vehicle size is normal, fill the normal veh array
if(v.getSize().equals(Constants.NORMAL_SIZE))
{
    for(int i = 0; i<normalVehicles.length; i++)
    {
        //if norm veh array element is null, add the appropriate value to it
        if(normalVehicles[i] == null){normalVehicles[i] = v;}

        else{normBool = true;}
    }
}
//if veh size is large put it in the large veh array
else if(v.getSize().equals(Constants.LARGE_SIZE))
{   
    for(int iL = 0; iL<largeVehicles.length; iL++)
    {
        if(largeVehicles[iL] == null){largeVehicles[iL] = v;}
        else{largeBool = true;}
    }
}

return res;
}//end method
```

Comment: I  have so far managed to populate the normal array with the repeated entries of the first element in the array

Comment: You need to quit iterating through the loops when you find and overwrite a null entry. Try using `return` or `break` to do that. Or even better, keep track of how many large & normal vehicles you have recorded over time, and you don't have to do any looping inside of `loadVehicle`.

Comment: Are you allowed to use linkedList? sounds better

Comment: Thank you Ruz, and i do appreciate the suggestion joe, I think that is bit beyond the intended scope but I do like encountering new techniques that will assist me once I leave these archaic arrays behind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you cannot use builtin **LinkedList** class too, then do this:

Add the following code in your Vehicle class:

> ```
> class Vehicle(){
>
>      //YOUR OTHER PIECES OF CODES ...
>
>      private static Vehicle firstLargeVehicle;
>      private Vehicle nextLargeVehicle;
>      private int index;
>
>      public void setIndex(int index){
>           this.index = index;
>           if(index == 0) Vehicle.firstLargeVehicle = this;
>      }
>
>      public int getIndex(){
>           return index;
>      }
>
>      public void setNextLargeVehicle(Vehicle nextLargeVehicle){
>           this.nextLargeVehicle = nextLargeVehicle;
>      }
>
>      public Vehicle getNextLargeVehicle(){
>           return nextLargeVehicle;
>      }
>
>      public addLargeVehicle(Vehicle newVehicle){
>           this.nextLargeVehicle = newVehicle;
>           newVehicle.setIndex(index + 1);
>      }
>
>      public getListSize(){
>           Vehicle lastOne = this;
>           while (lastOne.getNextLargeVehicle() != null){
>               lastOne = lastOne.getNextLargeVehicle();
>           }
>
>           return lastOne.getIndex() + 1;
>      }
>
>      public static Vehicle[] largeVehiclesToArray(){
>           Vehicle[] result = new Vehicle[firstLargeVehicle.getListSize()]();
>           Vehicle pointer = firstLargeVehicle;
>           for (int counter = 0; pointer != null; counter ++){
>               result[counter] = pointer;
>               pointer = pointer.getNextLargeVehicle();
>           }
>
>           return result;
>      }
>
>  }
> ```

And in your main loop, do something like the following code:

> ```
>   Vehicle vehicle = null; 
>   for(Vehicle newVehicle : allVehicles) {
>        if (newVehicle.isLarge()){
>             if (vehicle == null) {
>                  vehicle = newVehicle;
>                  vehicle.setIndex(0);
>             }else{
>                  vehicle.addLargeVehicle(newVehicle));
>             }
>        } 
>   } 
>
>   Vehicle[] largeVehicles = Vehicle.largeVehiclesToArray();
> ```

And the same story goes for normal vehicles.
Any question ?

Comment: thats a lot of code for my inquiry, I greatly appreciate the effort and I'm implementing right away

Comment: you are very welcome @Philip, please let me know if anything went wrong with the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your loops like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < normalVehicles.length; i++)
{
  if(normalVehicles[i] == null)
  {
    normalVehicles[i] = v;
    break;
  }
}
// if last slot isn't null then it's full
normBool = normalVehicles[normalVehicles.length-1] != null;
```

Comment: I like the single line bool check and value assignment. thank you